# Finding a word specified in the command line from a file

Tags: java, command-line, client-server

I'm trying to search a word specified in the command line from a file. However, when it is being run, it displays nothing. What could the problem be? Here is a part of my code. Thank you for helping me!

```
class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        private Socket client;
        private Scanner input;
        private PrintWriter output;
        private ArrayList<String> quotes;
        public ClientHandler3(Socket socket, String file) {
            client = socket;
            try {
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
                String line = reader.readLine();
                try {
                    int ctr = 0;
                    quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(line != null){
                        quotes.add(ctr, line);

                        ctr++;
                        line = buffer.readLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
                output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void run(String[] args) {
            String target;
            String message = "";
                target= args[3];
                for(int i = 0; i<quotes.size(); i++){
                    if(quotes.get(i).toUpperCase().contains(target.toUpperCase())){
                        output.println(quotes.get(i));
                    }
                }
                output.println("|");
            try {
                if (client != null) {
                    System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
                    client.close();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that causes the problem. I tried it though. :) The problem is, I think, in the `run()` method because there is where I search the word.

Answer (score 1):

Your client reads `args[1]` (the host), `args[2]` (the port), but not `args[3]`, the word to be searched.

Your code is also hard to read, because it doesn't respect the standard naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter, whereas methods start with a lowercase letter. Your code does the inverse.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I'm new in programming. I'll do that next time. About `args[3]`, I stored it in `String target` and I passed `target` to `client` method and `clienthandler` class.

Comment: I didn't see that. But target is initialized after the call the Client(). So when Client sends it to the server, it's still null. You should make it a local variable and read it in `Client()`, just like the host and the port.

Comment: Thanks. I now did `target = args[3];` in the `client` method. The problem now is how to "pass" `args[3]` in the class `clienthandler`.

Comment: You need to read the word from the socket's input stream: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()); String word = reader.readLine();`

Comment: Thanks! I did that and made the `target` in `run(String[] args)` equals `args[3]` as well. (Pls. see edit) But it still does not work. :o

Comment: Take some time to actually understand what you're doing. It makes no sense to read what the client enters as the third argument in the server. Read the api documentation of the classes you're using. You're creating a reader, and don't read anything from it. You're creating a thread without overriding the run() method (without any argument).My advice: put your server code and your client code in two separate classes. You're confusing yourself by having them in the same one. And go step by step. Start by just reading what the client sends. When it works, try to send a hard-coded answer, etc.